# Why DC is not used for long distance voltage transmission? (Tesla vs Edison 2015)

Tags: ac, high-voltage, power-engineering, hvdc

It seems this question has been marked [duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/64604/why-are-the-power-transmission-distribution-systems-ac-and-not-dc) but I believe the answers given here is much more in detail.
[image: HVDC diagram]Why we are still using AC voltage for long distance voltage transmission. As we know with our current technology we could step up and and step down DC voltage thus reducing the Amps and losses. Dc current would have no harmonics or frequency issues. We may convert DC back to AC at receiving end.

Reasons for my arguments are [Advantages of HVDC over HVAC transmission](http://electrical-engineering-portal.com/advantages-of-hvdc-over-hvac-transmission)

[image]